# Registering a IExceptionLogger OWIN versus WebApiConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

We have a set of RestFul services developed using WebApi 2. These will be hosted on Azure. I have an implementation of the IExceptionLogger to log all unhandled exceptions.

The logger can be registered in the pipeline as follows

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //Register the ExceptionLogger
            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger());

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Or it could be setup as a Owin middleware as follows

```
public static class SetupExceptionHandlers
{
    public static IAppBuilder SetupFilters(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger());

        return builder;
    }   
}
```

And then registered in the pipeline as follows

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            app.SetupFilters(config);
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }
    }
```

Trying to understand what the better/correct way to do this is. I have registered it both ways and don't see any difference in the behavior. I have also tried to keep both the registrations at the same time and it still works(no exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

There's no outright benefits to using either method (e.g. you can't use DI either way and there's no changes to pipeline behavior).

Obviously creating the handler extension method allows you to have cleaner & more maintainable code. Especially if you're going to be distributing the middleware.